# Disable IsSelected default color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

When I click on a TreeViewItem ItemClicked() is called.

C#:

```
    public void ItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TreeViewItem ClickedNode)
        {
            if (ClickedNode.HasItems) // Its a parent node
            {
                if (CtrlPressed)
                {
                    var SelectedChild = TreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem; // Have to do this manually since the sender is parent???
                    SelectedChild.Background = Brushes.Black;
                    SelectedChild.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

In my XAML I disabled IsSelected default colors:

```
<Grid>

    <TreeView Name="TreeView">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp"
                             Handler="ItemClicked"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="Black" />
        </TreeView.Resources>

    </TreeView>

</Grid>
```

So now when I control-click on a node it won't be displayed in black, but all white. So the transparent seems to override the just set Brushes.Black. Foreground color seems to go through.

First Question: the sender is not the actual clicked node, but its parent node. Why is that? I have to figure out if it is a parent node manually and then get .SelectedItem manually too. How do I fix that?

Second Question: How do I fix the overriding of the colors? I don't want anything when IsSelected is true at all...

Comment: Is the child a TreeViewItem or a TreeViewNode?  Your code is : sender is TreeViewItem ClickedNode

Comment: Everything in mit TreeView is a TreeViewItem. I didnt even know there are different objects..

Comment: You should only be asking one question at a time. Which post do you pick if someone can answer one question but not the other?

Comment: First Question
Child treeviewitems are within their parent. A treeviewitem is a headered itemscontrol. Take a look at e.OriginalSource.